# Recompiling the java.exe laucher

Tags: compilation, launcher, java

I notice a src.zip file containing some Java source bundled with the standard JDK install. When unzipped I notice C source files for the Java launcher, etc.

However, when I download the Java platform source from download.java.net/jdk6/source, I see a different folder structure and different files being laid down. Whats the difference between the two?

I want to recompile the Java launcher (rebuild java.exe using java.c). I can only find java.c in the src.zip file that is part of the JDK but not its dependencies. They seem to exist in the full source code bundle of the JDK. However, java.c itself seems missing in the full JDK source bundle. This is confusing to me.

Can someone please clarify the difference and how best to go about rebuilding only java.exe?

Comment: Apologies. I found java.c in the j2se/src/share/bin folder in the full JDK source. I would still like to know the difference between the source available as part of the JDK install the full source download and rationale for different folder structures in the two.

Thanks,
Ranjit

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are missing `jni.h`, etcetera.  Take a look in `$JAVA_HOME/include` for the missing header files.

"The difference" is that the JDK that you download from the Oracle website is not OpenJDK.  Rather it is *based on* the OpenJDK codebase, with a bunch of extra proprietary stuff.

It is your choice which one you use.